# Separating out zipped iterator into single iterator?

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, iterator, numba

My code has two 2D numpy arrays, `z` and `weights`.
I'm iterating over them like this (while transposing them):

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

for y1, w in zip(z.T, weights.T): # building the parameters per j class
    temp_g = sm.WLS(y1, iself.X, w).fit()
```

This is fine, until I started using Numba in order to speed up my code. With Numba, I get this error:

```
numba.error.NumbaError: (see below)
--------------------- Numba Encountered Errors or Warnings ---------------------
        for y1, w in zip(z.T, weights.T): # building the parameters per j class
------------^
Error 82:12: Only a single target iteration variable is supported at the moment
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To fix this problem, I suppose I could simply do this:

```
for y1 in z.T:
   for w in weights.T:
       temp_g = sm.WLS(y1, iself.X, w).fit()
```

But I'm not too good at python yet so I just want to know if that's the best way to do it? Or if there's another more optimal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Numba doesn't support *assignment unpacking*. Assign to *one* target, then address the two indices in the tuple:

```
for y1_w in zip(z.T, weights.T):
    temp_g = sm.WLS(y1_w[0], iself.X, y1_w[1]).fit()
```

Here `y1_w` is a tuple containing the paired-up elements of `z.T` and `weights.T`, so a tuple of two elements. You can address each element with indexing.

You can *probably* use assignment unpacking outside the `for` statement, in the loop body:

```
for y1_w in zip(z.T, weights.T):
    y1, w = y1_w  # unpack the zip pair 'manually'
    temp_g = sm.WLS(y1, iself.X, w).fit()
```